# Error on Uploading Program to ESP8266 via Foca v2.2 (USB to TTL Adapter)

Tags: esp8266

### BACKGROUND

To test the capability of uploading program to ESP8266,  I use an empty program with only a blank setup function and a blank loop function. The result showed me that there are a **espcomm_sync error** and a **espcomm_open error**. Any idea to solve this problem?

---

### HARDWARE

### [image: Foca v2.2] [image: ESP8266]

---

### PIN CONNECTION

```
  Foca v2.2 <-> ESP8266
        TXD <-> RXD
        RXD <-> TXD
        DTR <-> RST

Arduino UNO <-> ESP8266
        GND <-> GND
       3.3V <-> Vcc
```

---

### PIN DIAGRAMS

Foca v2.2
[image]

ESP8266
[image]

---

### ON LINUX UBUNTU 15.04

[image]

---

### ON WINDOWS 10

[image]

### REFERENCE

---

Bring IoT to Arduino, together [Getting Started] - http://www.arduinesp.com/getting-started

Comment: On windows your problem is possibly there is no COM4. On ubuntu possibly your esp is not boot-up in flash mode. For esp connection do not connect RST and GPIO0, try resetting and flash mode by hand and dont forget to connect GPIO15

Comment: @MertGülsoy - How to set to flash mode by hand and where is the GPIO15? Thank you.

Comment: as you uploaded the picture I realized that you're using ESP01. That module has no GPIO15. So you can ignore it. With this module pull GPIO0 to GND and issue a reset. Then start uploading. After reset completes you can make GPIO0 floating. Then start uploading.

Comment: @MertGülsoy - You means that I need to connect GPIO0 to GND for a while and then press upload button again? Sadly, it seems not work. Something I did wrongly?

Comment: 1) CH_PD -> vcc
2) gpio0 -> gnd
2.5) tx-RXD, rx-TXD
3) issue reset
4) disconnect gpio0
5) try upload. 
if it does not work try reversing the tx-TXD, rx-RXD